# Why won't python understand Pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I just downloaded Pillow and every time I try to import the module it shows an error, saying there is no module named Pillow. I am using the newest version of python, and it says that Pillow has been downloaded through 2.7 in the files directory. If anyone knows the answer that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, Jamal

Comment: when I try importing it,it says there is no module named Pillow. But when I go into terminal it says that Pillow is downloaded

Comment: The module name is `PIL`.

Comment: What is the code to import it then?

Comment: `import PIL` will import Pillow

Comment: You may be missing an egg dependency, are you on windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pillow module is installed using this command:

```
pip install pillow
```

but it's imported  with this:

```
import PIL
```

If that doesn't work, you may have something wrong with your python or pip installation. 
[Here](https://python-forum.io/Thread-PyGame-Install-and-Troubleshooting) is a short tutorial for troubleshooting pip when it doesn't work. It's written for pygame, but it can be used for other modules as well.